# Uso do map() em python

Tags: python

Pesquisando nesse nesse site https://pythonhelp.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/map-reduce-filter-e-lambda/ vi o uso do map(). Porém no terminal o primeiro exemplo não está imprimindo uma lista.

```py
import math
lista1 = [1,4,9,16]
lista2 = map(math.sqrt,lista1)
print(lista2)

<map object at 0x00C84770>
```

Mas quando é feito um list comprehensions funciona, 
`[math.sqrt(x) for x in lista1]`, tem como saída um lista correta. Qual está sendo a diferença?

Comment: map retorna um interador, vc pode desempacotar assim,   lista2 = [*map(math.sqrt,lista1)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `map()` é uma função que retorna um objeto iterador. Você precisa usá-lo um for loop ou convertê-lo para um outro tipo de sequência como por exemplo `list`. Veja como ficaria:

```
import math
lista1 = [1,4,9,16]
lista2 = list(map(math.sqrt,lista1))
print(lista2)

[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Comment: Funcionou, obg : )